# Spring Boot trying to resolve bean not in my xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to test a class that simple shutdown the application:

```
@Component
public class ShutdownManager {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationcontext;

    public int shutdown(int returnCode) {
        return SpringApplication.exit(applicationcontext, () -> returnCode);
    }
}
```

The test case I created is this:

```
public class ShutdownManagerTest {
    @Test
    public void should_shutdown_gracefully() {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(TestClass.class);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = app.run();

        ShutdownManager shutdownManager = (ShutdownManager)context.getBean("shutdownManager");

        int result = shutdownManager.shutdown(10);

        assertThat(result).isEqualTo(10);
    }

    @SpringBootApplication
    @ImportResource("classpath:/core/shutdownmanagertest.xml")
    private static class TestClass {
        public TestClass() {
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        }
    }
}
```

My shutdownmanagertest.xml contains only one bean:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="shutdownManager" class="com.mycodebase.ShutdownManager" />

</beans>
```

However, when I run this, it complains that:

```
Field myOtherService in com.mycodebase.MyTask required a bean of type 'com.mycodebase.MyOtherService ' that could not be found.
```

The class MyTask is in the same package of the ShutdownManager which contains a field myOtherService which has an @Autowire annocation. But it is not defined in my test xml which contains just one bean.

Can someone help me understand why it tries to resolve a bean that is not in the context?

Comment: you need to add more code in order to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing that because that's how `@SpringBootApplication` works.

[@SpringBootApplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html):

> This is a convenience annotation that is equivalent to declaring @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and **@ComponentScan**.

[@ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)

> If specific packages are not defined, **scanning will occur from the package of the class that declares this annotation**.

So everything in the same or a subpackage of ShutdownManagerTest is being picked up.